# Make tabs be visually 4 spaces long but 1 column only

Tags: tabs, column

I indent my code with tabs and I want my tabs to be visually 4 spaces long but to be 1 column only.
Currently with my configurations my tabs are 4 spaces long but also 4 columns long and I can't find anywhere how I can make it 1 column long only, but I know it is possible because I've used a configurations on another computer that did that.
Unfortunately I can't get back to that computer anymore.

If needed here is my `.emacs`:

```lisp
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(defvaralias 'c-basic-offset 'tab-width)
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the distinction between "visually N spaces" and "N columns only".  What kind of columns are you talking about?

Comment: The variable `tab-width` is buffer-local, which means that any major-mode can change the value when said mode is enabled.  Setting a default value of a buffer-local variable by using `setq-default` is never a guarantee as to what the value will be after a major-mode is enabled.  What major-mode are you using and what is the value of `tab-width` (*after* said major-mode is enabled) when type type `C-h v` aka `M-x describe-variable`?  You can obtain the name of the major-mode a variety of ways including, but not limited to `C-h m`.